# Enterprise Architect -> How to get the edge of the end node using a SQL Query on the .eap-File (.mdb)

Tags: sql, ms-access, enterprise-architect

I have to draw some EA diagrams using only the .eap file without an installed EA on the server. So I am opening it as MDB-File via ODBC.

I know there is the attribute `t_diagramlinks.Geometry` (with edge={1,2,3,4})  and the Attribute `t_connector.Start_Edge` and the attribute `t_connector.End_Edge`.

The table `t_diagramlinks` with the attribute `Geometry` is diagram-dependent.
The table `t_connector` with the attributes `.Start_Edge` and `.End_Edge` is not diagram-dependent --> there could be connections that haven't been drawn on a diagram.

I know that the SX, SY, EX, EY of `t_diagramlinks` are coordinates relative to the origin of each node that is drawn on a diagram.

**Problem: EX / EY sometimes is zero and isn't painting the end line to the edge of the node. I guess it has something to do with mouse release position.**

"My Interpretation" below is what my renderer produces based on my assumptions.

"EA Interpretation" is what EA is actually rendering and which I would like to see in my renderer as well.

[image]

***Questions***

- I am using the csv-Value EDGE in `t_diagramlinks.Geometry` - but where
  do I find this for the end node?
- For which purpose are the attributes Start_Edge an End_Edge in the
  table `t_connector` when it is not diagram-dependent?

Comment: So is "My Interpretation" actually what you would like to see from EA? A connector leading to the inside of an element??

Comment: Hi no - this is currently what my web application is drawing because of EX=0 and EY=0 - i would like to see it like it is drawn in EA.

Comment: Ah ok. I'll try to elaborate a it more on how EA is doing its rendering. Please also clarify the question on Sparx' forum (you might link to this thread as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much. I choosed to calculate the End-Edge mathematically:

[image: End Edgge node]

My problem was, that i wasn't able to detect the end edge of the target endnode on a link relation. Further more there are 8 different link types, that are determining the layout of the links. So as Thomas mentioned i had to detect the last point before the endpoint. If it is a path, the last node of the path is the point before the endpoint. If there is not a path, the startnodes starting point is the last point before the endpoint. But if there is a path defined and the link mode has been set to 1 i may not process the connection path, because the Conn_Path property is containing a customized line - but after customizing the user has selected to have a direct link (it will not be deleted).

The mathematic behind is used as linear function y=m*x+b and the lines are described by 4 straight lines which are appropriate to the edges of the endnode.

So you can do the following algorithm:

[image: Page one of the algorithm]

[image]

The complete algorithm is using the following approach:

1.) Determine straight line between start- and endnode (there are 2 special cases if the line is completely horizontal or vertically parallel to the coordinate system)

2.) Create a rectangle which consists of four straight lines (2 vertical / 2 horizontal lines)

3.) Determine the intersection of the first straight line with the rectangles lines

4.) Exclude point that are not consisting to the rectangle

5.) Determine the point on the rectangle with the shortest distance => this is the searched end edge point

The written javascript code i have used to do the routing is the following:

```
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Erzeuge eine eigene Link-Klasse für das Routing der Pfeile, die von Hand gezogen wurden
// und über spezielle Attribute in der EAP-Datei definiert werden
// Ruft die Superklasse von go.Link im Konstruktor auf
function MultiNodePathLink() {
    go.Link.call(this);
}
go.Diagram.inherit(MultiNodePathLink, go.Link); // Erben von go.Link

// ignores this.routing, this.adjusting, this.corner, this.smoothness, this.curviness
/** @override */
MultiNodePathLink.prototype.computePoints = function () {

    // Die this Referenz ist hier ist ein geerbter ein go.Link. der bei Links
    var startNode = this.fromNode;
    var startNodeX = startNode.location.M;  // X-Koordinate vom Startknoten
    var startNodeY = startNode.location.N; // Y-Koordinate vom Startknoten

    var endNode = this.toNode;
    var endNodeX = endNode.location.M;  // X-Koordinate vom Startknoten
    var endNodeY = endNode.location.N; // Y-Koordinate vom Startknoten

    var startNodeData = startNode.data; // Das sind die Daten
    var endNodeData = endNode.data; // Das sind die Daten

    // Die Link-Daten
    var linkProperties = this.data;
    //** Das Feld Style in [t_diagramlink] bestimmt die Connector-Darstellung  **/
    // http://www.capri-soft.de/blog/?p=2904
    /*
     *  1 = Direct                    Mode=1
     *  2 = Auto Routing              Mode=2
     *  3 = Custom Line               Mode=3
     *  4 = Tree Vertical             Mode=3;TREE=V
     *  5 = Tree Horizontal           Mode=3;TREE=H
     *  6 = Lateral Vertical          Mode=3;TREE=LV
     *  7 = Lateral Horizontal        Mode=3;TREE=LH
     *  8 = Orthogonal Square         Mode=3;TREE=OS
     *  9 = Orthogonal Rounded        Mode=3;TREE=OR
     */
    var styleStringArray = linkProperties.style.split(";");
    var mode = -1;
    var tree = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < styleStringArray.length; i++) {
        if (styleStringArray[i].trim().indexOf('Mode=') > -1) {
            mode = styleStringArray[i].replace('Mode=', '');
        }

        if (styleStringArray[i].trim().indexOf('TREE=') > -1) {
            tree = styleStringArray[i].replace('TREE=', '');
        }
    }



    // In der Tabelle t_diagramlinks in der Freitextspalte "Geometry" wird in einem CSV-String
    // gespeichert, wie der Link letztendlich auf dem Diagram gezogen wurde
    var geometryString = linkProperties.geometry.split(";");
    // SX and SY are relative to the centre of the start object
    var sx = geometryString[0].replace("SX=", "");
    var sy = geometryString[1].replace("SY=", "");
    // EX and EY are relative to the centre of the end object
    var ex = geometryString[2].replace("EX=", "");
    var ey = geometryString[3].replace("EY=", "");

    // SX=-67;SY=-43;EX=-12;EY=-40;EDGE=3;$LLB=;
    // LLT=;LMT=;LMB=CX=30:CY=13:OX=11:OY=-2:HDN=0:BLD=0:ITA=0:UND=0:CLR=-1:ALN=1:DIR=0:ROT=0;
    // LRT=;LRB=;IRHS=;ILHS=;

    // EDGE ranges in value from 1-4, with 1=Top, 2=Right, 3=Bottom, 4=Left (Outgoing Point of the Start Object)
    var edge = geometryString[4].replace("EDGE=", "");

    // Hier beginnt das Custom-Routing
    this.clearPoints();
    if (linkProperties.start_object_name == 'System Verification Test Reports' && linkProperties.end_object_name == 'System test specifications') {
        var test = 'irrsinn';
    }
    // Hier werden die Wege definiert für das gecustomizte Link Routing
    // Geht der Link nach oben oder unten wird die Y-Koordinate des Startknotens genutzt (Weil Orthogonales Routing)
    var startConnX = null;
    var startConnY = null;
    if (edge == 1) { // Ecke oben
        startConnX = Math.abs(startNodeX) + Math.abs((startNode.actualBounds.width / 2) + new Number(sx));
        startConnY = Math.abs(startNodeY);
    }
    else if (edge == 3) { // Ecke unten
        startConnX = Math.abs(startNodeX) + Math.abs((startNode.actualBounds.width / 2) + new Number(sx));
        startConnY = Math.abs(startNodeY) + new Number(startNode.actualBounds.height);
    }
    else if (edge == 2) { // Ecke rechts
        startConnX = Math.abs(startNodeX) + startNode.actualBounds.width;
        startConnY = Math.abs(startNodeY) + Math.abs((startNode.actualBounds.height / 2) - new Number(sy));
    }
    else if (edge == 4) { // Ecke links
        startConnX = new Number(Math.abs(startNodeX));
        startConnY = Math.round(startNodeY) + Math.round((startNode.actualBounds.height / 2) - new Number(sy));
    }
    else {
        alert('Die Edge konnte nicht entdeckt werden! Ist der Geometry String in der EAP Datei richtig?');
    }

    this.addPoint(new go.Point(Math.round(startConnX), Math.round(startConnY)));

    // Abfrage: Gibt es einen letzten Path Punkt?
    var lastPathPunkt=false;
    var lastPathPunktX, lastPathPunktY;

    if (mode != 1)
    {
        // Routing über die Zwischenwege
        if (typeof linkProperties.conn_path !== "undefined" && linkProperties.conn_path !== "") {
            var splittedArray = linkProperties.conn_path.split(";");
            if (splittedArray.length > 1) {
                // Hier ist mindestens ein Wert vorhanden da auch der erste mit Semikolon abgeschlossen wird im Path vom EA
                for (var i = 0; i < splittedArray.length - 1; i++) {
                    var einMittelPunkt = splittedArray[i];
                    var mittelPunktArray = einMittelPunkt.split(":");
                    this.addPoint(new go.Point(Math.abs(new Number(mittelPunktArray[0])), Math.abs(new Number(mittelPunktArray[1]))))
                    lastPathPunktX = Math.abs(new Number(mittelPunktArray[0]));
                    lastPathPunktY = Math.abs(new Number(mittelPunktArray[1]));
                    lastPathPunkt = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Wenn es keinen Pfad gab,muss der letzte Punkt mit dem Startknoten identisch sein
    if (lastPathPunkt == false) {
        lastPathPunktX = Math.abs(Math.round(startConnX));
        lastPathPunktY = Math.abs(Math.round(startConnY));
    }

    // End-Routing
    // Der Endpunkt in EA in Document Coordinates
    var endConnX = Math.abs(endNodeX) + Math.abs((endNode.actualBounds.width / 2) + new Number(ex));
    var endConnY = Math.abs(endNodeY) + Math.abs((endNode.actualBounds.height / 2) - new Number(ey));

    // Spezialfälle bei horizontalen und vertikalen Linien:
    if (endConnX == lastPathPunktX) {
        // Es liegt eine vertikale Gerade (z.B. von oben nach unten) vor
        this.addPoint(new go.Point(Math.round(lastPathPunktX), Math.round(lastPathPunktY)));
        this.addPoint(new go.Point(Math.round(endConnX), Math.round(endConnY)));

    } else if (endConnY == lastPathPunktY) {
        // Es liegt eine horizontale Gerade (z.B. von rechts nach links) vor
        this.addPoint(new go.Point(Math.round(lastPathPunktX), Math.round(lastPathPunktY)));
        this.addPoint(new go.Point(Math.round(endConnX), Math.round(endConnY)));
    } else {
        // Es ist keine Gerade sondern ein Gerade, die mit y=m*x+b beschrieben werden kann

        // 1.) Gerade zwischen Start- und Endpunkt ermittelnhn
        //      Ye-Ys
        //  m = -----    b=Ys-m*Xs oder b=Ye-m*Xe
        //      Xe-Xs
        var m = (endConnY - lastPathPunktY) / (endConnX - lastPathPunktX);
        var b = lastPathPunktY - m * lastPathPunktX

        // 2.) Ermittlung der horizontalen und vertikalen Geraden des Rechteckes und dem Schnittpunkten
        // Die Geraden, die das Rechteck definieren:
        var rY1 = endNodeY;
        var rY2 = endNodeY + endNode.actualBounds.height;
        var rX1 = endNodeX;
        var rX2 = endNodeX + endNode.actualBounds.width;
        // (rX1, rY1) -zu-> (rX2, rY2)

        // Horizontale Geraden:
        //     y - b
        // x = -----
        //       m


        var lengthToPoint = [];

        var sX1 = (rY1 - b) / m; // S1(sX1|rY1)
        if (sX1 >= rX1 && sX1 <= rX2) {
            // Der Schnittpunkt sX1 ist am Rechteck
            // Distanz: d=SQRT((y2-y1)^2+(x2-x1)^2)
            var dS1 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rY1 - lastPathPunktY, 2) + Math.pow(sX1 - lastPathPunktX, 2));

            lengthToPoint.push({
                "distanz": dS1,
                "x": sX1,
                "y": rY1
            });

        }

        var sX2 = (rY2 - b) / m; // S2(sX2|rY2)
        if (sX2 >= rX1 && sX2 <= rX2) {
            // Der Schnittpunkt sX2 ist am Rechteck
            // Distanz: d=SQRT((y2-y1)^2+(x2-x1)^2)
            var dS2 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rY2 - lastPathPunktY, 2) + Math.pow(sX2 - lastPathPunktX, 2));

            lengthToPoint.push({
                "distanz": dS2,
                "x": sX2,
                "y": rY2
            });
        }

        // Vertikale Geraden:
        //
        // y = m*x + b

        var sY1 = m * rX1 + b; // S3(rX1|sY1)
        if (sY1 >= rY1 && sY1 <= rY2) {
            // Der Schnittpunkt sY1 ist am Rechteck
            // Distanz: d=SQRT((y2-y1)^2+(x2-x1)^2)
            var dS3 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sY1 - lastPathPunktY, 2) + Math.pow(rX1 - lastPathPunktX, 2));

            lengthToPoint.push({
                "distanz": dS3,
                "x": rX1,
                "y": sY1
            });
        }

        var sY2 = m * rX2 + b; // S4(rX2|sY2)
        if (sY2 >= rY1 && sY2 <= rY2) {
            // Der Schnittpunkt sY2 ist am Rechteck
            // Distanz: d=SQRT((y2-y1)^2+(x2-x1)^2)
            var dS4 = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(sY2 - lastPathPunktY, 2) + Math.pow(rX2 - lastPathPunktX, 2));

            lengthToPoint.push({
                "distanz": dS4,
                "x": rX2,
                "y": sY2
            });
        }

        // Sortiere alle Punkte nach Distanz - der mit der kleinsten Entfernung isses
        lengthToPoint.sort(function (a, b) { return a.distanz - b.distanz });

        if (lengthToPoint.length > 0)
        {
            this.addPoint(new go.Point(Math.round(lengthToPoint[0].x), Math.round(lengthToPoint[0].y)));
        }
        else
        {
            this.addPoint(new go.Point(Math.round(lastPathPunktX), Math.round(lastPathPunktY)));
        }


    }

    return true;
};
// end MultiNodePathLink class
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am using in t_diagramlinks.Geometry the csv-Value EDGE - but where
>   do i find this for the end node?

You need to use Euclide. SX,SY/EX,EY are relative shifts from the shortest center connection between start and end element.

> For which purpose are the attributes Start_Edge an End_Edge in the
>   table "t_connector" when it is not diagram-dependend?

They are used for qualified properties.

**Edit**: To elaborate a bit more on your basic issue. `t_diagramlinks.path` holds bending points for the connector (if any are specified). So in order to find the point where a connector actually joins an element you have to find the nearest bend to that element. Now between this bend and the middle of the element you will have a *natural* attachment point. Relative to that the SX-Y (/EX-Y) are added to make the manually shifted rendered attachment point.

The above goes with a grain of salt. I never verified the nitty gritty but used my stomach from seeing the numbers. I might look into that in detail to update my Inside book but can't promise.

**2nd Edit**: Now that I know that "My Interpretation" is what your renderer produces based on your assumptions, here's the (most likely; see above) story. In order to render a connector EA will use the following information:

- the frame coordinates of the two connected elements
- calculated from the coordinates the middle point of the elements
- the path property of the connector (if not empty)
- the nearest bending point to the relevant elements (if not empty)
- the shift factors SX-Y and EX-Y for the connector

Starting from the start element's middle point you draw a virtual line to either the nearest bending point or the middle of the end element (unless see below). That way you can calculate the virtual attachment point at the element's rectangular frame (even use cases have a rectangular frame). Now you shift that point by SX-Y which will (/should?) always travel along the edge of the element frame. Now you have the virtual attachment point for the start element.

On the other side (the end element; my "unless" from above) you would do a similar thing to calculate the virtual attachment for the end. What I don't know is the real order in which EA is doing that (I have no code insight). So if you have manual offsets on both sides the calculation will give different results depending on the order to draw the virtual connection to the other side (so: is the shift on the other side respected or not). Basically I think you can neglect that for 99.9% of all cases and the rest is just irrelevant noise.

So now you know the virtual end points you either connect them directly or, if a path is give, you connect them via the bending points.

Again: all with a grain of salt. It's just observation from the outside but likely not too far away. There's also the fact that you have different line styles with rounded edges (not taken into account here) and bezier lines (even more dragon land).

Comment: I'll give you a down vote for that query blurb. Remove it and the down vote will be turned in an up-vote for the rest.

Comment: The problem is, that "Euclide" is drawing the end nodes somewhere but not on a edge - ex and ey sometimes is zero. The SQL Statement works for me but i do not know where to find the edge of the end node - i get Geometry and Start_Edge and End_Edge - but t_connector.End_Edge is not diagram dependend. I have removed the SQL Query as you requested although it worked.

Comment: Problem: EX / EY sometimes is zero and isn't painting the end line to the edge.

Comment: About the deleted SQL: I made so much subqueries because i had the problem that the "normal" joins ate some lines. With that subqueries it worked after some experiments. I added a picture instead of it.

Comment: I have elaborated on the way the EA renderer works (to the best of my humble knowledge).

Comment: Thx Thomas! I have to check this out tomorrow i currently have to finish another task!